# mysql insert/update if exist in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have a table with an id(primary key) and a name. User can either add a new row or update an existing row. One way is I can check whether the id is posted back, then I will update, otherwise it is a new record and I will insert. Is there a way to do it in one sql statement, like the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. Thanks.

Note:
The reason I ask this is the primary key is auto-increment and it will be null when I retrieve it from the $_POST;

Comment: Well... yes. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?!

Comment: why you updating id only update values except id

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c,d)
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d;
```